# jerky USB keyboard signal

Tags: usb, cables

I have made this contraption in order to quickly switch one keyboard between a PC and a laptop:

[image]

The keyboard hooks into USB_A and it gets routed to either J1 or J2 depending on the position of a 3PDT switch.

I am using similar lengths of cables at both J1 and J2 (0.5 - 0.6 meters; less than 2 ft). Plug either one of them into the laptop - works. Plug either one of them into the PC and it will work sporadically. And when it does, give a few seconds to a few hours and it will stop working. Oh, and yes, plugging the USB keybd directly into the PC works as expected. What gives here ?

**edit**

More photos:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's unlikely to be an impedance problem as keyboards (unless they're some fancy sort with extra features) don't generally use high-speed USB. A ground loop, perhaps?

Comment: This kind of thing "breaks all the rules" - keyboards are supposed to be low speed devices (unless yours has a built in hub in which case the external connection could be high speed even though the internal connection of keyboard to hub is still low) so things should be fairly lenient, but still, if it's bad enough...  Can you `edit` a picture into your post?

Comment: Unfortunately your pictures don't really show enough detail to tell if your implementation is introducing a problem, but things like screw terminals in a USB signal path are *highly* unusual.   The thing you are trying to build is available for purchase as a product, if your goal is usability you should probably either buy one, or re-do this keeping things as compact and neat as possible, with particular emphasis on trying to keep the wires of the USB pairs at as consistent a spacing and length as possible.  This could also be something like a noisy power supply...

Comment: @Hearth Hmm, I recall that I have had a broken GND on the contraption PCB at one point; there was no GND between J1 and J2; oddly, the cable with no GND connection at all would work fine in the laptop.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Eh, the thing is taped to that side now... hard to take it off. And those are not screw terminals but some sort of an epoxy mound around the directly soldered wires. Could a ferrite bead close to the PC's USB-in port help any ?